# How to detect and handle the time difference between server and user in WordPress?

Tags: php, plugin-development, date-time, timezones

I have to make a custom plugin for a WordPress website. In this plugin, I have to create a meta box for a post where I have a time and date field that decides that when the post will be expired and will be moved in the trash. but the problem is that website has 2 admins situated in two different time zones. One admin is in GMT+2 and one admin is in GMT+4 and the webserver is running according to the GMT standard time.

Now the problem I am facing is that if admin 1 is set to post to expire at 6 PM then the post gets expire at 8 PM instead of 6 PM. On the other hand, 2nd admin sees the setting as expiring at 6 PM while he should see it as expiring at 8 PM.

How can I detect time differences before submitting them to the database? On other hand, I want the database time to be converted into local time to show in the value tag in input.

Can anyone help in this way, please?

Comment: Welcome to wpse! please add the code that is handeling the time and date checks, without it it would be imposible to answer. For now what I can say is it seems that you have a timezone problem, user and server are in different time zones, PHP has a function to set the time zone, you can put it at the beginning of the function that handles the check, [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.